# Error installing Gensim: "Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution."

Tags: python, pip, gensim

Im trying to install gensim using pip but i'm getting:

```
"Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 377, in setup_py
import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
ImportError: No module named extern"
```

Other posts have suggested running

```
 pip install -U setuptools
```

which reports to have successfully installed the package.

```
Installing collected packages: setuptools
Successfully installed setuptools-21.0.0
```

However, running the gensim pip install command:

```
pip install gensim
```

just gives the first error again.

any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Mac OSX? Using the system Python?

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar issue when installing SciPy Stack.

Try to use: `pip install --user setuptools`

Instead of using: `pip install -U setuptools`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error with another library. It took me two steps, but it could be overkill.

```
# apt-get install python-setuptools
# pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: Based on filepaths in the question, the OP is running OSX system and not a Linux distribution with `apt-get` available.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you bypass using your systems python.  You could mess something up and then your computer wouldn't work.  [Install Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) into your home directory.  This python distribution etc.. will get you up and running with 195 libraries or so.  You can use the built in command "conda install gensim" in order to get gensim without needing setuptools.

Answer (score 0):

I just meet similar problems.
Just try to uninstall all setuptools's dependency.
Especially unisntall pkg_resources in your situation.
And then install setuptools again. Pip will solve all dependency problems for you.
Then you should able to install gensim smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

You need to have admin permission this worked for me 
 `sudo pip install setuptools`